# Need to Handle Laravel Exception and, Logging details mismatch error

Tags: laravel

I have tried to handle the exceptions on Handler class in my laravel project

```
            if(!env('APP_DEBUG', false)){
                return view('errors.500');
            } else {
                return parent::render($request, $exception);
            }
```

Errors are redirecting to my page. but in the login page user name or password mismatch also redirecting to that page.

**in the login error need to redirect to the login page,not to the common error page. how can handle it?**

i have using default laravel auth login.

this is my Handler.php file,

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        // Render well-known exceptions here

        // Otherwise display internal error message
        if(!env('APP_DEBUG', false)){
            return view('errors.500');
        } else {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code from the `register` method in `Handler.php`?

Comment: i have one changed render function. Handler.php added to the question

Comment: You're not limiting which exceptions manage that code statement, so technically any exception will result in the `errors.500` view being returned as long as `!env('APP_DEBUG', false)` evaluates `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to check for 500 errors manually .If you want to show custom error message for 500 erorrs in production then publish default laravel views for errors

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

This will generate views for errors in following path

```
resources/views/errors
```

To customize 500 erorrs .Edit following path

```
resources/views/errors/500.blade.php
```

Also make sure this will only show when

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

[image]